# make post title become mailto subject wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, title, mailto

I'm trying to make a post title to become mailto subject in wordpress.
I'm using this code

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">LINK TEXT</a>
```

but when I test it, it doesn't show the blog title in the subject, it shows this text in the subject line :

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

I'm i missing something ?

thanks!

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure to be on a php page? Your PHP does not appear to be interpreted

Comment: ee. no! sorry i'm pretty new to wordpress. ok if I put that code in a php file in my wordpress. then How do I make that fonction appear in my blog post?

Comment: You have to write your code on the `single.php` or `single-post.php` template file

Comment: ALRIGHT! it works :) thanks !

Comment: If i'm using visual composer for the content, is there anyway to put it within a row in my content? If not, it will just stay where it is

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with visual composer

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, [wp_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/#source-code) should be what you need:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com?subject=<?php wp_title() ?>">LINK TEXT</a>
```